# Data is not displayed on page

Tags: angular

I am running into problem with display my data on page after a post request to my API. I have never ran into this problem before and I have no idea what causes it.This is just some easiest implementation but it just not working.

My Service:

```
 getCourseInfo(data): Observable<any> {
    const id = parseInt(data);
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/TblUnimeCourses/getCourseInfo/` + id;
    return this.http.get(url);
 }
```

My resolver for the page:

```
  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      return this.courseService.getCourseInfo(route.paramMap.get("id"));
  }
```

My Component:

```
  export class IntroComponent implements OnInit {
    courseInfo: CourseInfo;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.courseInfo = this.route.snapshot.data.data;
       console.log(this.courseInfo);
    }
  }

  export interface CourseInfo {
     courseTitle: any;
     coursePrice: number;
  }
```

My console log:

```
  courseCode: "IT101"
  coursePrice: 300
  courseTitle: "Information Technology"
  description: "Monash University Foundation Course"
  introduction: "Introductory course"
```

My template: ( sorry I pasted wrong code here while i was trying other approach, then I double checked my own code, it is using courseInfo this object for display. so the problem is still not fixed yet. Also the question mark I added after this object doesn't solve this problem.)

```
  <div class="intro-title">
     <h2>{{ courseInfo?.courseTitle }}</h2>
  </div>
```

However, the courseTitle is never displayed even I have got my data back and I have console log it I can see them in the development tool.

Comment: Thanks guys. I lately found out I was adding this function inside a different component with similar name. Just remind me again some little detail could fuck me good time......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
<div class="intro-title">
   <h2> {{ courseInfo?.courseTitle }} </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are populating this.courseInfo while you are using courseDetail on the template which is a @input to the component. So either you use this.courseInfo or set data in courseDetail which is then given to your component as @input.

Comment: I have remove the @input and only use the courseInfo in the component, but the problem still remain. It is not displayed on the page?

Comment: Would it be cache problem?

Comment: I dont think its a cache issue. moreover you can try assigning the initially courseInfo as null and add a *ngIf on parent div for courseInfo to be not null this should work

Answer (score 0):

I think the `courseDetail` input is undefined. You should try using `courseInfo?.courseTitle` instead.

Comment: sorry that was a mis-type in the question. I have correct my question but the problem is still remain.